# Elasticsearch failed to resolve host

Tags: elasticsearch, chef-infra, kibana

We have upgraded elasticsearch from 2.3.1 to 5.x version and the problem is that sync between multiple elasticsearch instances are not happening and I can see this particular exception in the logs which was not occuring in 2.3.1 version.

Configuration:

```
elk_nodes_ips = []
elk_nodes_results = search(:node, "roles:elasticsearch")
unless elk_nodes_results.empty?
  elk_nodes_results.sort!{|node1, node2| node1.name <=> node2.name}
  elk_nodes_results.map{ |server| 
elk_nodes_ips.push(server['hostname'])}
else
  elk_nodes_ips.push('127.0.0.1')
end

data = "[#{elk_nodes_ips.join(",")}]"

elasticsearch_configure 'elasticsearch' do
  # if you override one of these, you probably want to override all
path_data  node['ElasticsearchWrapper']['path']['data']
path_logs  node['ElasticsearchWrapper']['path']['logs']
configuration ({
      'network.host' => '0.0.0.0',
      'http.port' => 9200,
      'discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts' => data
    })
  action :manage
end
```

Exception:

```
[2017-07-21T06:20:31,976][WARN ][o.e.d.z.UnicastZenPing   ] [ElasticSearch-i-051b2c3eea79d3f62] failed to resolve host [[ElasticSearch-i-036a95f01a737f4a2]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid bracketed host/port range: [ElasticSearch-i-036a95f01a737f4a2
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:871) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:852) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:674) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.UnicastZenPing.lambda$null$0(UnicastZenPing.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569) [elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
[2017-07-21T06:20:31,984][WARN ][o.e.d.z.UnicastZenPing   ] [ElasticSearch-i-051b2c3eea79d3f62] failed to resolve host [ElasticSearch-i-051b2c3eea79d3f62]]
java.net.UnknownHostException: ElasticSearch-i-051b2c3eea79d3f62]: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:897) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:852) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:674) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.UnicastZenPing.lambda$null$0(UnicastZenPing.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569) [elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
[2017-07-21T06:20:35,010][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [ElasticSearch-i-051b2c3eea79d3f62] new_master {ElasticSearch-i-051b2c3eea79d3f62}{_WzMZ_7mScOoIBjeA8Hoow}{N46xjTXWT8qIQNuRONh8PA}{172.18.50.225}{172.18.50.225:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
```

elasticsearch.yml file

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: ElasticSearch-i-012d2c56e9920ec75
path.conf: "/etc/elasticsearch"
path.data: "/vol/data/elasticsearch"
path.logs: "/vol/log/elasticsearch"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: "[172.18.51.98]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem: `data = "[#{elk_nodes_ips.join(",")}]"`

You mean to do this later on: `'discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts' => elk_nodes_ips,`. No string munging needed, the custom resource will handle that for you (via YAML serialization).

Answer (score 0):

Take a careful look at this error message

`failed to resolve host [[ElasticSearch-i-036a95f01a737f4a2]`

you spot two brackets in front. One stems from the log format ES uses, but the other one seems to have sneaked into your hostname somehow. Can you verify by checking the `elasticsearch.yml` file?

Comment: Added the yml file, could you please check it

Comment: do not put the array in double ticks, but the element inside the array, as in `["172.18.51.98"]` - otherwise the element inside double quotes is used as a hostname